# EKS + ALB Ingress not working on differents manifest

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

I'm trying to use the same ALB for multiple services, but when I define a new entry or rule in a manifest other than the main one, it is not added to the AWS ALB.

The only rules that appear are the ones I created in the alb-ingress.yaml manifest, the rules from app.yaml don't appear.

ALB print: https://prnt.sc/IfpfbHGvkkFi

alb-ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alb-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: eks-test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "alb-dev"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: ""
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /status
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: status
                port:
                  number: 80
```

app.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  namespace: dev
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: app
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: eks-test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "alb-triercloud-dev"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '1'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: service-a.devopsbyexample.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: echoserver
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Each ingress is bound to the ALB, so you need to modify your ingress resource to add a path.

See here: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/how-it-works/#ingress-creation

Comment: I can't understand your suggestion, am I not already doing this when using "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name"?
I redid my tests based on the link you gave me, but the problem remains. When I declare rules with another code block, like the examples I showed above, they are not created in the ALB, only the rules of the first code block remain. Can you tell me exactly what is wrong or what is missing in my code that I showed as an example?

Comment: “alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name”

This annotation is exclusive within a group.